# Big male cat attacked my kitten help me to find some answer

Tags: cats

My kitten is 5 months old and she was bitten by a big male cat; he attacked my kitten's forehead and she was injured. My kitten is recovering from the injury, but when she sleeps on one side, saliva starts coming out of his mouth, and starts weeping and screaming. I don't understand why my kitten starts drooling when he sleeps on one side, but when he sleeps on the other side nothing happens.

Comment: You need to consult your veterinarian (the same one you took the kitten to after the attack), not a bunch of untrained random internet strangers. If you didn't take the kitten to a vet already, you need to do that *immediately*.

Comment: did the kitten piss the cat off? That would be a possibility.

Comment: Is your question about how to care for the kitten? If so, see Allison C's comment. Or is your question about why adult male cats attack kittens? If so, it's about genetics and "nature red in tooth and claw."

Comment: has your kitten been at the vet? you are saying the kitten are recovering but what you say about her is a sign of serious injury.

Comment: This may have simply been a display of dominance by the older cat. However, I am concerned that the injury needs to be treated by a Vet.

Comment: A cat bite (as in "attack", not "playing") - is a serious injury, for man as well as fellow cat, and one should consult a doctor. The wound's deep and become inflamed inside, even if it looks healed on the surface.